# How to query Firestore database with the reference type in springboot?

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a list of users who have referred by another user. I have a user collection in firebase as follows:

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "isReferred": "true",
    "phone": "43532",
    "place": "India",
    "referredBy": "User/Lb53139TJpmlIO9lsQxD",
    "votedFor": "John Doe"
}
```

I want a service class that can fetch users referred by id `Lb53139TJpmlIO9lsQxD`. `referredBy` type is set to `reference`. Can someone show me an example or a reference on how to query the reference type?

Comment: You can provide a DocumentReference object to the query if you want to filter on a reference type field.

Comment: @DougStevenson: Thanks! Can you provide some reference or documentation link?

Comment: There is no mention in the docs. You can look at the client source, it just try it to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating this answer as a community wiki since it's based on Doug Stevenson's comments.

You can provide a DocumentReference object to the query if you want to filter on a reference type field. There is no reference for this in the documentation but you can follow the example below for the document you shared in the question:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference referralUserRef = db.collection("User")
                                      .document("Lb53139TJpmlIO9lsQxD");
db.collection("User")
  .whereEqualTo("referredBy", referralUserRef)
  .get()
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
          //Do something
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AngularFireStore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

constructor(public df: AngularFireStore) {}


//Get list of users
getAllAvailableUser(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.userList = this.df.collection('users').valueChanges();
    return this.userList;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This doesn't look like java, as the question is tagged.